# Neo4j Cypher - Returning nodes and their nested nodes of the same type

Tags: neo4j, nested, cypher

I want to be able to return a list of `Item` nodes with their list of nested `Item` nodes contained within a `Box`. Because the relationships between the `Item` nodes and their nested `Item` nodes may be different (E.g. `WHEELS`, `WINDOWS`, `LIGHTS`), I would like to write a query that skips over the relationships and returns any nested `Item` node and their `Item` children because an `Item` will either have at least one `Item` child or none (thus resulting in empty children list).

I want to be able to do this with just a `Box` identifier (E.g. `boxID`) being passed.

[image]

**NOTE:** I'm new to Neo4j and Cypher so please reply with a (fairly) detailed answer of how the query works. I want to be able to understand how it works. Thanks!

E.g.

```
MATCH (iA: Item)-[r]->(iB: Item)-[r]->(b: Box) 
WHERE b.boxID = $boxID
RETURN COLLECT(iB.itemID AS ItemID, ib.name as ItemName, COLLECT(iA.itemID as ItemID, iA.name as ItemName, COLLECT(...) ) AS ItemChildren)
```

The `COLLECT(..)` part confuses me. How do I return an `Item` node and all of its `Item` children and all of that childs `Item` children, and so on until empty children? Is there a better way to `MATCH` all of the nodes?

Answer (score 3):

That is very easy using a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) pattern:

```
MATCH (b:Box)-[:CONTAINS]->(:ItemInstance)-[*]-(i:Item)
WHERE b.boxID = $boxID
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT i) AS ItemChildren
```

The `DISTINCT` option is needed because the variable-length relationship result can return the same item multiple times.

This query also acknowledges the relationship directionality shown in your diagram. The `CONTAINS` relationship pattern specifies the appropriate directionality, but the variable-length relationship (`-[*]-`) specifies no directionality since your data model does not use a consistent direction throughout the tree starting at an `ItemInstance`.

*Caveat: unbounded variable-length relationships can take a very long time or even run out of memory, depending on how big your DB is and how many relationships each node has. This can be worked around by specifying a reasonable upper bound on the length.*